# merge national hydrography dataset files

Tags: arcgis-10.1, geometric-network, hydrography

I'm having difficulty merging datafiles from the NHD while still keeping functionality as a geometric network. I'm using ArcGIS 10.1, so the [USGS merge tool](http://nhd.usgs.gov/tools.html#merge) isn't an option.

Using the medium resolution [staged NHD files](ftp://nhdftp.usgs.gov/DataSets/Staged/SubRegions/FileGDB/MediumResolution/), I've tried 1) merging the NHDFlowline files and then building a geometric network - results in a network with "Indeterminate Flow" and 1 type [12 error](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002r00000006000000); and 2) putting two NHDFlowline files into a new Feature dataset inside of a file geodatabase, then constructing the geometric network - results in a network with "Indeterminate flow" also.

Not sure if I am mis-specifying the geometric network attributes, missing a step or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, turns out I wasn't honoring the wisdom of the beginner's mind and I jumped right to an assumption that my problem was way more complex than simply not having run the [`Set Flow Direction` tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000016r000000). Entries in the attribute table of the NHDFlowline file suggest that "WITH_DIGITIZED_DIRECTION" is the right parameter to go with - and it seems to check out visually.